# Iterate over results of value_counts() on a groupby object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like `df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5],'Col1':['Y','Y','Y','N','N','N','Y','Y','Y','N','N']})`. What I would like to do is group by the 'ID' column and then get statistics on three conditions:

1. How many groups have only 'Y's
2. How many groups have at least 1 'Y' and at least 1 'N'
3. How many groups have only 'N's

`groups = df.groupby('ID')  groups.Col1.value_counts()`

gives me a visual representation of what I'm looking for, but how can I then iterate over the results of the value_counts() method to check for these conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [`pd.crosstab()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) may be more suitable for your use case.

### Code

```
df_crosstab = pd.crosstab(df["ID"], df["Col1"])

Col1  N  Y
ID        
1     0  2
2     1  1
3     2  0
4     0  2
5     2  1
```

Groupby can also do the job, but much more tedious:

```
df_crosstab = df.groupby('ID')["Col1"]\
   .value_counts()\
   .rename("count")\
   .reset_index()\
   .pivot(index="ID", columns="Col1", values="count")\
   .fillna(0)
```

### Filtering the groups

After producing `df_crosstab`, the filters for your 3 questions could be easily constructed:

```
# 1. How many groups have only 'Y's
df_crosstab[df_crosstab['N'] == 0]

Col1  N  Y
ID        
1     0  2
4     0  2

# 2. How many groups have at least 1 'Y' and at least 1 'N'
df_crosstab[(df_crosstab['N'] > 0) & (df_crosstab['Y'] > 0)]

Col1  N  Y
ID        
2     1  1
5     2  1

# 3. How many groups have only 'N's
df_crosstab[df_crosstab['Y'] == 0]

Col1  N  Y
ID        
3     2  0
```

If you want the number of groups only, just take the length of the the filtered crosstab dataframe. I believe this also makes automation much easier.

Comment: Thank you for sharing nice answer, with good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
groups = df.groupby('ID')  
answers = groups.Col1.value_counts()

for item in answers.iteritems(): 
    print(item)
```

What you are making is a series from `value_counts()` and you can iterate over them.  Note that this is not what you want.  You would have to check each of these items for the tests you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you group by 'ID' and use 'sum' function, you will have all letters in one line for each group. Then you can just count strings to check your conditions and take their sums to know the exact numbers for all of the groups:

```
strings = df.groupby(['ID']).sum()

only_y = sum(strings['Col1'].str.count('N') == 0)
only_n = sum(strings['Col1'].str.count('Y') == 0)
both = sum((strings['Col1'].str.count('Y') > 0) & (strings['Col1'].str.count('N') > 0))

print('Number of groups with Y only: ' + str(only_y), 
      'Number of groups with N only: ' + str(only_n), 
      'Number of groups with at least one Y and one N: ' + str(both), 
      sep='\n')
```